# async await inside function not working properly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, relayjs, relaymodern

I have this function, that i need to define an async function inside it:

```
  _refetchConnection = (page) => { // query for cursor page

    const refetchVariables =  async (fragmentVariables) => {
    let pageCursor;
    if(page !== 1) {
      const getAfterCursorQueryText = `
        query($count: Int!, $cursor:String) {# filename+Query
          viewer {
            publicTodos (first: $count, after: $cursor) {
              edges {
                cursor
                node {
                  id
                }
              }     

           pageInfo { # for pagination
            hasPreviousPage
            startCursor 
            hasNextPage
            endCursor 
          }         
            }
          }
        }`;
      let cursor = fragmentVariables.cursor;
      let count = 5;
      const getAfterCursorQuery = { text: getAfterCursorQueryText };
      const result = await this.props.relay.environment._network.fetch(getAfterCursorQuery, {cursor, count});

      pageCursor = result.data.viewer.publicTodos.pageInfo.endCursor;

    } else if (page === 1) {
      pageCursor = null;
    } 

      return {
          cursor: pageCursor,
          count:5 
        }
  }
    this.props.relay.refetch(refetchVariables, null);
  };
```

but there's no returned value on refetchVariables, it only had when I do not use async but i need to perform await for this code, and I need access on fragmentVariables:

```
const result = await this.props.relay.environment._network.fetch(getAfterCursorQuery, {cursor, count});
```

maybe making refetchVariables not an async works? but I have no idea how to code it. help? btw this is the value returned on async refetchVariables:

```
ƒ refetchVariables(_x2) {
                    return _ref3.apply(this, arguments);
                  }
```

Comment: i think you need to return a promise

Comment: this returns promise: await this.props.relay.environment._network.fetch(getAfterCursorQuery, {cursor, count}); had no idea how to do it in es5, can I ask u for help on that? I am so confused

Comment: `async` functions return a Promise instance, you need to use a `then()` callback to get what you returned in the function, ie `refetchVariables().then(cursorCountObj=>console.log(cursorCountObj))`

Comment: I was thinking it'd work like function and .then is optional

Comment: ill post a possilbe solution

Comment: @TimCodes i need access on default arg fragmentVariables

Comment: try below if it doesnt work let me know, you could just use promies here i think

Comment: are you trying to pass the acual fucntion to relay.refetch or the returned values ?

Comment: using  let rVars = await refetchVariables() i would have to make _refetchConnection  async. yes  @TimCodes

Comment: looking at relays docs one sec

Comment: yes, I would not have access on default fragmentVariables by doing that too

Comment: Please show us what `relay.refetch` does with the callback, and when it calls it what it does with the promise that the asychronous function returns.

Comment: sorry i ran out of time to work on this, refetch either takes a function that returns  new variables or the acutal vars, https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/refetch-container.html

Comment: you need to make your fucntion sig too look more like this https://github.com/wix/react-fullstack-seed/blob/master/src/actions/index.js#L12, good luck